# Maximum Acceleration for NASA's Transport Crawler while carrying Saturn V

Tags: launch-site, kennedy-space-center, crawler-transporter

I was reading about the [transport crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crawler-transporter) and one detail that seems to be not covered in any of the lay-person's easily accessible literature is the recommended acceleration for the transport while carrying a Saturn V rocket. It is normally reported the crawler would only move at 1mph/1.6kph while carrying a load, but how quickly was it accelerated while carrying a load is not. I did a cursory search but kept getting drowned  in results about Saturn V's own acceleration.

While I imagine there was a specification for maximum acceleration, if none can be found I would accept a rough estimate that would accomplish this.

Comment: The only thing I ever remember seeing about this (for the shuttle stack) was not basic acceleration lmiits but vibrational excitations. The "operational fix" was to roll out slower.

Comment: I don't know, but I suspect it's somewhere between really, really slowly and really, really, **really** slowly.

Comment: A detailed road test of this vehicle was published in an April 1st edition of Road and Track back in the day. They were unimpressed with the 1/4 mile time and criticized the fuel economy. However, they were REALLY impressed by the roof rack.